# Creating DLL for MT4 or MT5?

Tags: dll, mql, mt4

i want to make DLL for Metatrader however unlike MQL programming i didn't find any good source to learn on this subject

can anyone point me to a website or book etc so i study those

thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 3):

Here are few of the sources for creating DLLs for MT4/5 with C++ and C#(for MT5)

C++

[Latest Article-DLL is made with VS2017](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/5798)

[Old one(just for reference)](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/18)

C#

[Windows Form Application on MT5 with C# DLLs](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/5563)

[Quotes Exporter with Managed(.NET) DLLs with C++ wrapper](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/27)